# Using C# DLL in C++ application - CoCreateInstance failing with error "class not registered"

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

I have a Interface and implementation in C# DLL. (MYDLL.dll)

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
////
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
////
}
```

I have created tlb from my C# DLL and imported in C++ application as below,

```
#import "MyDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

and calling COCreateInstance as below

```
IMyInterface *m_pIMyObj = NULL;

hr = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MyClass),NULL,CLSCTX_SERVER, __uuidof(m_pIMyObj),reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pIMyObj));
```

I am registering MyDLL.dll using below command,

```
regasm MyDLL.dll \codebase
```

> But CocreateInstance is failing with error "Class not registered".

As per my understanding, this error means MyDLL is not registered properly. Why the DLL is not getting registered?

I tried to use gacutil to register the MYDLL in gac; this also doesn't resolve the issue. Please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: There are two com registries. The 32 and 64 bit registries. Perhaps you registered in one, but look in the other.